# Problem using with() and join() in same query - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to order my product records by the column `nombre` inside the `marca` table that has certain text, so for achieving this, I need to do a join in order to be able to sort with a relationship table column, my query is as follows:

```
$productos = Producto::query();

$productos = $productos->with([
                    'traducciones' => function($query) use($idioma){
                        $query->where('idioma_id', $idioma['idioma_id']);
                    },
                    'categorias' => function($query) use($idioma){
                        $query->whereHas('traducciones', function($query) use($idioma){
                               $query->where('idioma_id', $idioma['idioma_id']);
                            });
                    },
                    'imagenes' => function($query){
                        $query->where('destacada', 1);
                    },
                    'opciones',
                    'marcas'
                ])
                ->join('marcas_productos AS mp', 'productos.id', '=', 'mp.producto_id')
                ->join('marcas AS m', 'mp.marca_id', '=', 'm.id')
                ->orderByRaw("CASE
                    WHEN m.nombre LIKE '%Camen%' THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                    END"
                )
                ->where('estado_producto_id', 1)
                ->paginate(8);
```

The first problem is that inside my relationships (the ones that are inside the `with` method) I'm getting empty results, but when taking off this part:

```
->join('marcas_productos AS mp', 'productos.id', '=', 'mp.producto_id')
                    ->join('marcas AS m', 'mp.marca_id', '=', 'm.id')
                    ->orderByRaw("CASE
                        WHEN m.nombre LIKE '%Camen%' THEN 1
                        ELSE 2
                        END"
                    )
```

I get correct results inside the relationships.

The second problem is that columns that are named the same (as the joined table columns) are being replaced, for example I have a column named `nombre` inside `marcas` table, but I also have a column named `nombre` inside `productos` table, and they are being overwritten, how can I add the `select` statement so I get my data correctly, take in mind that I need all fields from the tables from the relationships and the main producto table, but I just don't them to be overwritten.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Like this way `select('marcas.nombre as marcos_nombre', 'productos.nombre as productos_nombre')` but in this method you nedd to put all the field name. There is a raw query like this `select a.f as aaa, a.*
from Alphabet a;`

Answer (score 0):

So I checked the raw query that Laravel was generating and I don't know if you're aware that for eager loading using the `with` method, Laravel uses the SQL `IN` operator, so when I checked the query, it was sending 0 as a parameter, like: `WHERE IN(0)` so I just added all of the attributes from my `productos` table to the `select` statement since that included the `id` from the main table and worked perfectly:

```
$productos = $productos->with([
                    'traducciones' => function($query) use($idioma){
                        $query->where('idioma_id', $idioma['idioma_id']);
                    },
                    'categorias' => function($query) use($idioma){
                        $query->whereHas('traducciones', function($query) use($idioma){
                               $query->where('idioma_id', $idioma['idioma_id']);
                            });
                    },
                    'imagenes' => function($query){
                        $query->where('destacada', 1);
                    },
                    'opciones',
                    'marcas'
                ])
                ->join('marcas_productos AS mp', 'productos.id', '=', 'mp.producto_id')
                ->join('marcas AS m', 'mp.marca_id', '=', 'm.id')
                ->select('m.nombre AS nombre_marca', 'productos.*') //Added this
                ->orderByRaw("CASE
                    WHEN m.nombre LIKE '%Camen%' THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                    END"
                )
                ->where('estado_producto_id', 1)
                ->paginate(8);
```